# how to Capture and Upload Video in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

My application requirement is Capture camera video and upload to (Facebook , Youtube) simultaneously.
My question is can we get the camera stream and buffer and then upload while capturing is still in progress ?

I am now able to get capture video and store in isolated storage, but with out saving to isolated storage can we upload directly ?
If yes then how ?

-Romesh

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple question in this question so here are my answers:

- There is no *built-in* way to upload a video to sites like Facebook and Youtube.
- Uploading videos requires a lot of bandwith so uploading at the same time on two websites might require the user to have a solid internet connection (i.e. Wifi)
- Uploading a video stream in real time also seems hard because the phone will have to capture, potentially compress, and send the stream at the same time. Don't forget you're on a phone, with limited resources.

I think the best you can do is save the video stream to the Isolated Storage, and once the user has finished the capture, allow him to upload the video.

Comment: Thanks for reply Olivier
My main concern is can we get the camera stream (raw data) ?

Comment: Of course, here is how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394041(v=vs.92).aspx